# How to remove pre-loaded variables in PyCharm every time Python Terminal is Opened

Tags: variables, pycharm, global-variables

I've encountered an issue where every time I open a new a Python console, it becomes loaded with what looks like extraneous global variables. In addition, when I import different libraries, it seems the method associated with that library are also imported to the variable workspace. I'm not quite sure how it got to this point, but before, opening up a new python console would leave the variable workspace clear until I explicitly declare the variable. In addition, importing libraries would not save the various methods. Shown below is an example of what appears upon creating a new python console.

I've tried commands such as

`globals().clear()`
and

```
%reset
```

but to no avail.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there's a "Simplified Variables View" Option on the side which will fix that.

[image]